# How to create stylize hair shader

Tags: texturing, hair

I'm trying to find a way to create a stylize hair shader, similar  to the references image below. Specifically the highlighted part and the little details of the hair strand. I used to manually paint them but it not very time efficient  and the details is not always consistent in quality.

Hence, I'm wondering is there a way to replicate it through other methods? It don't need to be 100% identical to the references image just something similar would do.

Thank you in advances.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try it with a curve that you bevel with a second curve as *Bevel Object* and a third as *Taper Object*. For the material it looks like a painted picture (a bit more stylized than what I've used here), so maybe use an image editor then import into an *Image Texture* node? Then duplicate, and probably convert to mesh to work the shape a bit more precisely (keep it low-poly like in your picture):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You could also try a procedural material:

[image]

[image]

From what you say, in your reference image, the hair are painted, it makes things much easier, so maybe mix painted and procedural effects (particularaly bumps and glossy effects):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, while I have figure out how to make the hair model, I have reached a wall on the texture part. Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks painted but I wonder how he did the reflection part, is it part of the painting or is it glossiness?

Comment: you mean the references image ? I assume it it create by the in game engine.

Comment: see my edit, I hope what I mean is more clear

Comment: While I can't said for certain, I think  is quite possible it is hand paint (they might have create the glossy map base on the painted area as well)

https://imgur.com/a/JYzyfX2  

I compile some images of the references character and others. and I notice the highlighted area is always the same, disregarding the light source. Hence ,it is fixed to the hand painted area.

Comment: ok so it makes the things simpler  ;)    I was not able to get the same effect procedurally, In my opinion it makes it look nicer if hand painted. Maybe there's even no (or small) bump effect and it's all hand painted

Comment: I'm kind of hoping to move away to hand paint as it is not really flexible(In my opinion) , maybe I might need to find a in between to method. Anyhow, thank you so much for the guidance. I really appreciate it.

Comment: yes something between seems to be the best solution, only a bit of glossiness, and only a bit of bump

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this video and tell me if it helps https://youtu.be/t2XjdzzWCqI?t=849
OMG I'm a 100% sure I've watched a guy that used something to get exactly where u want but I don't remember what video it was... (complete character, hair, I don't know, it wasn't about hair shaders tho) I think it was Yan sculpts;

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, I'm currently working on another task at the moment. Hence, I unable to try out the video tutorial at the moment. I really do appreciate it, more option the better.  I will update you once I get back to the work on the hair. 

I learn from Yan sculpts as well, there where I got the idea of using bevel and taper method for stylize hair.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think I found the video I told to you about, the guy uses anisotropic shader. Have a look, he talks about it at 14:10.
https://youtu.be/t2XjdzzWCqI?t=850

Comment: Hey Pedro, welcome back.  You can use the Edit link at the bottom of your previous answer to add these details.  External links are fine as supplemental info, but try to include any details here that would help someone work through the problem.  Thanks for the contributions